# Render image in Views php field

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-views

I need to use the php field in Views GUI. I got it all setup but I just can't render my image. When using $row->field_image, I get an array containing [0] => 152. What's that ? Is that the entity of the image ?

How would I render my image in there ? In fact, just the url to the image style would be ok. This is Drupal 8.

Answer (score 0):

As it was just some basic validation, I ended up using twig, which works perfectly. In a "custom text" field, here's out it goes :

```
{% if field_image_item|trim is not empty %}
   <img src="{{ field_image_item }}" alt="{{ title }}">
{% elseif field_image_item_1|trim is not empty %}
   <img src="{{ field_image_item_1 }}" alt="{{ title }}">
{% endif %}
```

I guess I'll figure how to do it in php another time :/